# Form submit JS/JQuery Ajax call failing only in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, safari

I have a contact form that processes through google forms via a standard JQuery .ajax method, and redirects to a URL upon success or failure. It works perfectly everywhere except in the Safari browser (on all platforms). I've googled and found a lot of people with Safari form submission issues, but none that really fit this exact situation.

All browsers/platforms return a 200 success status except Safari. Instead of the success URL replacement, you get a 404 error every time with this browser.

Edit/Additional Info: Safari chops off the URL parameters in the Request URL, while all other browsers don't. ie: http://example.com instead of http://example.com?thank-you.

Here's my code, with exact URL and Google form field names removed. Any help with how to get it to work in Safari is appreciated.

```
function postToGoogleForms() {
  var name = $('#Name').val();
  var address = $('#Address').val();
  var city = $('#City').val();
  var state = $('#State').val();
  var zip = $('#Zip').val();
  var email = $('#Email').val();

  $.ajax({
    url: "(Google forms endpoint url here)",
    data: {
      "(Google forms input name here)":name,
      "(Google forms input name here)":address,
      "(Google forms input name here)":city,
      "(Google forms input name here)":state,
      "(Google forms input name here)":zip,
      "(Google forms input name here)":email
    },
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"xml",
    statusCode: {
      0: function () {
        window.location.replace("https://example.com?thank-you");
      },
      200: function () {
        window.location.replace("https://example.com?thank-you");
      }
    }
  });
}
</script>

<form onsubmit="return postToGoogleForms()" method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="Name" id="Name" required>
<input type="text" placeholder="Address" name="Address" id="Address" required>
<input type="text" placeholder="City" name="City" id="City" required>
<input type="text" placeholder="State" name="State" id="State" required>
<input type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" name="Zip" id="Zip" maxlength='10' required>
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="Email" id="Email" required>
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: 404 means the URL is wrong. Check the web console to see what URL it's trying to send the AJAX request to.

Comment: Yes, that's what 404 is. All browsers send to the correct URL, but Safari cuts off the URL parameter.

Destination URL: http://example.com?thank-you

Safari sends to: http://example.com

All other browsers send to: http://example.com?thank-you

Comment: The question says that the AJAX call is failing. But that URL appears in `window.location.replace()`, not the AJAX request. Which part are you really asking about?

Comment: Those are success/error functions *within* the jquery .ajax() call. Those are the instructions you give jquery on what to do based on the outcome of the request.

Comment: Is that the only part that's failing? You can do `window.location.replace()` without using AJAX, so is the AJAX request even relevant to the question? Does it work properly if you do that outside the success functions?

Comment: The URL replacement isn't going to work in Safari regardless. Safari cuts the URL parameters off when redirecting.

Comment: I just tried `window.location.replace("http://www.google.com/?search=foo")` from the Javascript console in Safari and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it's something else within the jquery ajax, then. I've seen a million complaints online about Safari not working correctly with jquery ajax form success/fail redirects, but nobody has an answer yet. There must be something that can be altered to make it work. Possibly it's just submitted the form without hitting the ajax, I don't know.

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that `window.location.replace()` works differently in a callback function than in regular code. Can you turn your code into an executable stack snippet or jsfiddle so I can try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I actually fixed it. Safari needs to be told 'return false' at the end of your JQuery function, unlike all other browsers. Safari tries to reload like a normal submit action without being told explicitly not to. That's why it was losing everything. It would reload *after* the function completed.

Comment: That should happen in all browsers. The `onsubmit` action has to either return false or call `Event.preventDefault()`, otherwise the normal action happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Safari needs to be told explicitly not to reload the page at the end of a javascript function call onsubmit. If you don't tell it not to, it will just reload itself after completing the function. All other browsers are smarter than this. But not Safari.

So, I just added 'return false' to the end of the function.

Using the code from my OP, this is what it looks like with the added boolean.

```
// Blah blah blah other stuff that's unimportant to the answer
$.ajax({
  url: "(Google forms endpoint url here)",
  data: {
    (blah blah blah...)
  },
  type:"POST",
  dataType:"xml",
  statusCode: {
    (blah blah blah...)
  }
});
return false // This is what fixed Safari's handling.
}
```